Figma Plugin Development error: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow'
I am following along with the Figma Plugin Tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ExwP3Kmh-vI) and am getting stuck at the part where data is communicated from ui.html to code.ts.
Here is the submit script, which works up until the final PostMessage command:
  document.getElementById( 'submit-post' ).onclick = () => {
    const name = document.getElementById( 'name' ).value
    const username = document.getElementById( 'username' ).value
    const description = document.getElementById( 'description' ).value
    const darkModeState = document.getElementById( 'dark-mode-on' ).value
    const imageVariant = document.querySelector( 'input[name=variantGroup]:checked' ).value
    parent.postMessage( { pluginMessage: { name, username, description, darkModeState, imageVariant } } )
  }

The error generated is:
Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('null') does not match the recipient window's origin ('https://www.figma.com').

Because the development is happening locally in Visual Studio and the testing happening in a Figma window, I don't know how to resolve this issue.

Just in case this happens to anyone else, the solution is in adding the origin "*" to the postMessage call. It was there in the video demo I was following, but I didn't notice it. Basically, I had a typo.
In ui.html, make sure to add the origin "*" as the last argument of postMessage, ie:
   parent.postMessage( { pluginMessage: { date:data } }, "*" )

